# Writing text on icon of Menu in Android?

Tags: android, menu, icons, title

Can we set Title for a Menu Item in Android if it has an icon from drawable?

I have a icon for a Menu Item and if I set the icon then the title that is set for that Menu item is not visible.

Is this possible or not?

Hope to get a reply soon.

Regards
Sunil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely possible. Code like this works:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    menu.add(0, MENU_PAUSE, 0, "Pause").setIcon(R.drawable.pause);
    return true;
}
```

That creates a menu with one item in it, referred to by the int MENU_PAUSE (a unique identifier number), with the title "Pause" and the icon pause from res/drawable.

If that doesn't do it for you, could you show us your code?

---

Edit to provide more info based on comments:

It turns out the size of the images matters. The default Android menu images are 48*48 or smaller so it would seem that one must use similar sizes as well. Note: I didn't experiment with different screen sizes, this was only with 320x480 screen.

The alternative is to change the default background of the menu. These can be modified by setting a theme for your application in the manifest and then putting in these lines:

```
<item name="android:panelBackground">@drawable/yourMenuDrawable</item>
<item name="android:panelFullBackground">@drawable/yourOtherMenuDrawable</item>
```

The normal menu uses panelFullBackground, so that should be the one you replace first. You can find the default images Android uses in yourSDKfolder/platforms/xxx/data/res/, and they're called menu_background.9.png and menu_background_fill_parent_width.9.png.

I found this information by looking at the default [styles](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/styles.xml;h=c95ede77325740175c90d8de1504bc7fec4361a9;hb=HEAD) and [themes](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/themes.xml;h=17ea66a04d6797e551641ac0562d5cb6ca709c43;hb=HEAD) files available from the Android source code website

Comment: what is the size of the image that you are using? I have four menu items so it takes 2 * 2 and half of the screen for each icon. I am doing the same thing. The text is displayed if I dont add an icon. The icon in my case is of 160 * 68. So it occupies all the height and width of the menu item and so the text is not displayed. Can we display the text on top of icon? Please help.

Comment: Aha, you're right. The size of the image used matters. I hadn't noticed because I'm using the default Android images - they are all 48x48 or smaller, so it would seem you will have to resize your images.

Comment: Oh ok. Can we change the color of the Menu item from default white to something else, then place the icon of 48 * 48 on it and text below it? Can we do this? Let me know if you have any idea regarding this. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Thanks a lot Steve. It has solved my problem. One more thing, can we also change the number of menu items in one row. Currently it has 2 * 2 structure since I have 4 menu items. But what if I wanted to have them all in one row. Is that possible? Anyways, thanks a lot again.

Comment: I don't think you could do that without customising the menu code; by default it adjusts the the position/layout of the buttons depending on how many you have.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. Just add `withText` to the `android:showAsAction` attribute.
Example:

```
<item android:id="@+id/menu_save"
      android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_save"
      android:title="@string/menu_save"
      android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
```

See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html for more details :)